# How to loop program to continue from limits per query in indeed search api

Tags: javascript

Am trying to create a javascript function that execute a search query in indeed api like below:

https://resumes.indeed.com/rpc/search?q=sales&l=Orlando,FL&jk=&start=0&lmd=3day&radius=25&indeedcsrftoken=test_tokent

Total available result(s): 230

Each request, I only get 50 results. To continue,I have to loop a program to continue getting other results. So i have the following conclusion to make it work.

first: get the total number of loops to perform.

230 x 50 = 5

Where 230 is the total return results, and 50 is the limit on each return results.
So clearly, I simply need to loop program 5 times. But I think I have to structure limits into array like below so i can use/pass it to the query string on each loop.

let xlimit = [50,50,50,3]

xlimit .forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
url = "https://resumes.indeed.com/rpc/search?q=sales&l=Orlando,FL&jk=&start=0&limit="+ item +"&lmd=3day&radius=25&indeedcsrftoken=test_tokent";
}

I think this will work, by finding the way how to structure limits like this:

let xlimit = [50,50,50,3];

Let me know, how could i do that, or help me find a much simplier or proper way to do that.

Your help is much appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Update: Create a JS fiddle for this. Follow link below.

```
    let text = "";
    const limits = [50, 50, 50,3];//NEED HELP TO CREATE THIS ARRAYS
    const starts = [51,101,151,1];
    limits.forEach(myFunction);

    document.getElementById("executedQueryString").innerHTML = text;
     
    function myFunction(item, index) {

        url = "https://resumes.indeed.com/rpc/search?q=sales&l=Orlando,FL&jk=&start="+starts[index]+"&limit"+item+"&lmd=3day&radius=25&indeedcsrftoken=test_tokent";
      text += url + "<br>"; 
    }

    
    let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    let min = document.getElementById('min');
    let max = document.getElementById('max');
    let availableResult = document.getElementById('available-result');
    let resultAvailableValue = document.getElementById('result-available-value');
    let pageAvailableFromGrossResult = document.getElementById('page-available-from-gross-result');
    let expectedResult = document.getElementById('expected-result');
    let expectedPagenumberFromExpectedResult = document.getElementById('expected-pagenumber-from-expected-result');


    submit.addEventListener("click", getResultValue);


    function getResultValue() {

        let url = "https://resumes.indeed.com/rpc/search?q=sales&l=Orlando,FL&jk=&start=0&lmd=3day&radius=25&indeedcsrftoken=test_tokent";

        /**validate form value**/
        if ( (availableResult.value !== '') || (availableResult.value != undefined) ) {

            pageAvailableFromGrossResultValue = Number(availableResult.value)/50;
            expectedResultValue = Number(max.value) - Number(min.value);
            expectedPagenumberFromExpectedResultValue = expectedResultValue/50;

            resultAvailableValue.innerHTML = Number(availableResult.value);
            pageAvailableFromGrossResult.textContent = pageAvailableFromGrossResultValue;

            expectedResult.textContent = expectedResultValue;

            expectedPagenumberFromExpectedResult.textContent = Math.ceil(expectedPagenumberFromExpectedResultValue);
            

        }//eof form validation
        
    }
```

Comment: Hello, this will work if you 230 records fixed, If you have no idea how much records will come in future then you have to change your logic, may I know records are fixed or not , and I open that link which you have mentioned but I'm getting "{"results":[],"refinements":[],"totalResultCount":0,"loggedIn":false,"keywords":[],"debugInfo":{},"rezAlertExists":false,"searchHash":"00000000","savedSearch":null,"originTk":"1h34g5m65kb7h800"}" this results.

Comment: @KrunalJethi I created a JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hotmarycorleone/rh85dumb/1/, the link/api from indeed will not work on your end if you are not loggedin and you have to provide a valid csrftoken from your cookie value. I wiish and hope you see the js fidlle provided.

Comment: @KrunalJethi To answer your question, NO, total numbers of return records or results are dynamic. Returned result numbers are NOT FIXED.

Comment: Yes got it, went through your fiddle, okay so now , can you please attach result of this "https://resumes.indeed.com/rpc/search?q=sales&l=Orlando,FL&jk=&start=1&limit3&lmd=3day&radius=25&indeedcsrftoken=test_tokent", so I can see what this return to us

Comment: https://imgur.com/5NJSlev

Comment: need access for second link

Comment: @KrunalJethi sorry sent a wrong link, my last comment is updated thanks

Comment: @KrunalJethi https://imgur.com/40WKHbG

Comment: @KrunalJethi Here is the first one screenshot https://imgur.com/5NJSlev

Comment: Here you can follow this link , I think I have done similiar like you but using different sample API , https://jsfiddle.net/xhtjdm17/

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. All paging APIs will let you know when they are done or at least serve you less than your paging number on the last result.
All you need to do is to set the increment to 50 and then call until you get less or no results (in the case where there is exactly a multiple of your counter

Answer (score 1):

you can use below logic to get data from API till pagination gets not over, let me know if you still need any clarification, Thanks

```
const a = async () =>{
let passengers = [];
let loopNeed = true;

for (let i = 0; loopNeed == true; i++) {
    let result = await fetch(`https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger?page=${i}&size=1000`);
  const resJson = await result.json();
  passengers = passengers.concat(resJson.data);
  if(resJson.totalPassengers <= passengers.length){
      loopNeed = false;
    console.log(passengers)
  }

}
}
a();
```

Comment: Yeah I see this but I mainly works on the result variable. I want to return only per say row 270 to 400 records out of 1000. So page should start from 270. And your example, seems like you're not having trouble getting result more than 50, but I am having one. So basically need to prepare data arrays to provide on each loop to continue

Comment: This is only demo purpose, you can change value in it and use this logic