# How to get the number of 50's and its exist number from number like 230

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have number like 230.
And 50 is always the limit.
I want to get the following data:

[50,50,50,50,30]

I should get four 50's and its exist number that is less than 50.

example 2.

Number = 400

I should get
[50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]

example 3:

Number = 110

I should get

[50,50,10]

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far and what's not working with your attempt?

Comment: So you want to do a Euclidean division? Given `a` and `b`, find `q` and `r` such that `a = b * q + r` and `0 ≤ r < b`?

Comment: When you say "exist number" I think you mean the "**remainder** after division by 50" which, for positive numbers, can be computed with `Number % 50`

Comment: @Wyck yes thats what I mean, the remainder

Comment: @NickParsons am trying to solve this issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495847/how-to-loop-program-to-continue-from-limits-per-query-in-indeed-search-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getResult(420, 50) = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20]

getResult(51, 50) = [50, 1]

getResult(12, 50) = [12]
```

This is a basic way of doing it using `%` which is the modular operator.

```
console.log(getResult(420, 50));


function getResult(input, num) {
  if (input <= num) return [input];

  arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(input / num); i++) {
    arr.push(num);
  }

  let remainder = input % num;

  if (remainder > 0) {
    arr.push(input % num);
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: You probably want an additional check around `arr.push(input % num);` to prevent it pushing 0 for something like `getResult(400, 50)`

Comment: @PeteGO thank you so much. This solves my problem. This is what am looking for. Hugs and kisses for you thanks. Kind of starting programming so am thankful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
function get50s(num){
  let res = [];
  while(num >= 50) {
    res.push(50);
    num -= 50;
  }
  if(num > 0) res.push(num);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to add an explanation of how your code behaves so that the OP and future readers get a better understanding. "Javascript" doesn't add much.

Comment: yeah, but this is as simple as it gets... at least people can know how to read code... this is not a textbook afterall...

Answer (score 0):

```
`function fifties(num) {
    let ans = [];
    while (num > 0) {
        if (num >= 50) {
        num -= 50;
        ans.push(50);
       } else {
          ans.push(num);
          break;
         }
   }
   return ans;
}
console.log(fifties(340));
```

$ node fifties.js
[
50, 50, 50, 50,
50, 50, 40
]

Comment: This one is a perfect one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).